# Generating a Triangular Matrix via a Vector MATLAB

Tags: matrices, matlab

How do I generate an arbitrary (size n) triangular matrix with a vector?

For example:

A=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10];

And the answer should be:

B=[1,2,3,4;
   0,5,6,7;
   0,0,8,9;
   0,0,0,10]

or

C=[1,2,3,4;
   2,5,6,7;
   3,6,8,9;
   4,7,9,10]

I have already tried hankel, triu and other functions of MATLAB, did not work out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = numel(A)/2-1; % compute size of output matrix 
B = zeros(n); % define B of required size
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:n); % ii and jj are row and column indices respectively
B(ii>=jj) = A; % fill in values in column-major order
B = B.'; % transpose to get result
```

Comment: Thank you so much; it was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

> `B = triu(ones(4));
>   B(B==1) = A;`

should do the trick.

Comment: Dear Martini. Thank you so much for taking time, but the result is not as same as the answer. It result: B=[1,2,4,7;0,3,5,8;0,0,6,9;0,0,0,10]

Comment: Just replace `triu` with `tril` and it works...

Answer (score 0):

I have completed it:

> `n=4;
>   A=1:n*(2*n+1);
>   B=zeros(2*n)
>   [ii,jj]=ndgrid(1:2*n);
>   B(ii>=jj)=A;
>   B=B.'
>   for i=1:2*n
>       for j=i:2*n
>           B(j,i)=B(i,j);
>       end
>   end
>   B`
>   
>   Answer is:
>   
>   `B =
>        1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
>        2     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
>        3    10    16    17    18    19    20    21
>        4    11    17    22    23    24    25    26
>        5    12    18    23    27    28    29    30
>        6    13    19    24    28    31    32    33
>        7    14    20    25    29    32    34    35
>        8    15    21    26    30    33    35    36`
>   
>   Thank you so much

Comment: Instead of the `B=B.'` and the two loops just add, `B(ii<=jj)=A;`. It's less code and more efficient, too.